Central Limit Theorem to determine sample size
Given a sample $X_1, ..., X_n \sim^{iid} $ Bern(p). I want to test $H_0: p = 0.49$ vs. $H_1: p = 0.51$.
How can I determine the sample size for which the probability of type I error (and type II error) is equal to 0.02?
I tried using the central limit theorem, but until now without any success. Can anyone help me out?

The alternative hypothesis is the opposite of the null, and 0.51 is not the opposite of 0.49, the opposite is !=0.49. Why these two values specifically? Are you trying to establish which of these two values is more likely? What if it's not any of these two values?

The CLT is a limit theorem.  Use it only in a theoretical context.

I got some hints from my tutor: I should use a test function that rejects $H_0$ when $\sum_i X_i $ is large. And: For the CLT, I should use the fact that $z_{0.98} \approx 2.05$, where $z_{0.98}$ is the 0.98-quantile of the $N(0, 1)$ distribution.
